# Certificate_unknown WSO2 API Manager 4.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

im using Api Manager 4.1 as API Gateway to send request endpoint backend. I try hit HTTP / HTTPS api endpoint from my API Project. but when i try HTTPS i always get 400 status.. when i check the log from apim. i got log

```
[2022-10-04 05:46:25,389]  WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[2022-10-04 05:46:25,445]  WARN - AccessConfiguration Error loading properties from file: access-log.properties
[2022-10-04 05:46:25,449]  WARN - MiscellaneousUtil Error loading properties from a file at from the System defined location: access-log.properties
[2022-10-04 05:46:25,451]  WARN - MiscellaneousUtil Error loading properties from a file at from the System defined location: access-log.properties
[2022-10-04 05:46:25,797]  INFO - DefaultKeyValidationHandler org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler Initialised
[2022-10-04 05:46:25,849]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
```

i try search and try fix like i find at my search like change it from deployment.toml, change configuration from api-manager.xml. try remake from new API project, and i enable CORS configuration. i always get 400. and credential_certificate. i try hit with endpoint from internal web browser at server and from external browser i access. i accepted all certificate like the reference search i got. but didnt work. maybe someone can helping about what i got. and i try hit with postman or with api-manager devportal try-out. and generate with token key but the result its same.

Comment: Did you change the default Keystores of the server?

Comment: on deployment.toml > 
[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "wso2carbon",   // there no change from there

Answer (score 0):

When an API is invoked from the Devportal UI (using the Try it feature), the browser sends the request to Gateway which has a self-signed certificate. Since the browser doesn't trust this certificate, the request fails throwing the below log trace on the wso2carbon.log.
WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown"

In this case, we have to explicitly tell the browser to trust this certificate.
For the development environments, if a self-signed certificate is being used, it can be imported to the browser. In that case, you can access the request URL (that gets displayed in the swagger UI) on a new tab of the same browser and trust the certificate from the browser.
Or else, you can use a CA-signed certificate for Gateway and import it to the truststore (This is the recommended way if you are in a production environment)

Regarding the postman invocation;

- Are you observing the same warn logs in the carbon logs for the postman call?
- Are you importing any certificate to postman or have disabled certificate validation?

Comment: let me ask about swagger UI. its that was at publisher at API Definition. to find that swagger UI and how to CA-signed certificate for gateway, and import to truststore. sorry many question, because i was new for this APIM 4.1